# Make audio + image in batch from a text file in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, batch-file, audio, text

I created, starting from some discussions here, a program that generates an audio file (output from tts) and an image from a word inserted in a text box.
es: I put the word "apple" in the textbox and the program creates "mela.wav" and "mela.jpg"
How do I create a batch to create more files from a list of words?
Sorry for my english!!

Comment: If you already have a C# Program, why use a batch instead of extending your program to take a list?

Comment: Sorry, I meant an extension of the program, not an external batch!

Comment: Well, you could use a multi-line text element instead of a single line textbox and do your thing for each line. (Loop over lines)

Comment: Thanks so much! I solved. now the only problem is to figure out how to create a video combining the audio file and image. until now i used ffmpeg outside the program. how can ffmpeg be integrated into the program for this specific function?